# i want to manage the format in java

Tags: java

```
public void listAllPatient()
{
    ArrayList<Patient> listPatient=curClinic.getAllPatient();
    System.out.println("Medicare Number" + "Name" + "Year Of Birth" + "Number of Visits");
    for(Patient p : listPatient)
    {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

}

public String toString()//code from patient class
{
    return medicareNumber + "  " + pName + "  " + brithDate + "  " +      getNumberOfVisit();
}
```

i want to show something like this

```
Medicare Number     Name        Year Of Birth       Number of Visits
3012 81822 8        Fred Smith  1957                13
2249 14567 9        John Adams  1928                2
```

Comment: Have a look at `String.format` and [for example](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Comment: `'\t'` may help you ;)

Comment: Or more precisely,`'\t'` and '`'\n'`';). Change your return of `toString()` method to:

`return medicareNumber + "\t" + pName + "\t" + brithDate + "\t" +      getNumberOfVisit()+"\n";`

Comment: modifying internals of `toString()` for one external requirement seems wrong policy.

Answer (score 1):

First take a look at [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) and [this for some examples](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Start by defining the header and data formats...

```
public static final String HEADER_FORMAT = "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s";
public static final String DATA_FORMAT = "%-20s %-20s %-20d %-20d";
```

Print the header...

```
System.out.println(String.format(HEADER_FORMAT, "Medicare Number", "Name", "Year Of Birth", "Number of Visits"));
```

Then for each `Patient`, format it's properties

```
for (Patient p : patients) {
    System.out.println(String.format(DATA_FORMAT, p.getMediacareNumber(), p.getName(), p.getDob(), p.getVisits()));
}
```

I choose not to use the `toString` method, as this might be used for other things and without the header, it's kind of useless.

This can generate something like...

```
Medicare Number      Name                 Year Of Birth        Number of Visits    
3012 81822 8         Fred Smith           1957                 13                  
2249 14567 9         John Adams           1928                 2
```

Comment: thanks i try this one. it also working, but there is a exception

Comment: java.util.lllegatformatconversionException:null(in java.util.formatter$formatspecifier)

Comment: I imagine one of your values is `null`

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use something like OpenCSV (with tab separators) to create an appropriate formatted dataset, the advantage being that you'd also be able to save it out and use it in external software too.