# Ascii table spaces

Tags: java

I have a ASCII table and I  want to make it to where I can place input and not affect spaces

```
System.out.println("._________________________.");
    System.out.println("|" + playerOneName + "                         " + "|");
    System.out.println("|-------------------------|");
    System.out.println("|Wins                   "+ playOneWin + "|");
    System.out.println("|Losses                 " + playOneLoss + "|");
    System.out.println("|_________________________|");
```

I  know it doesnt make sense to the context but If I do a random name like John. This is output

```
    System.out.println("._________________________.");
    System.out.println("|John                        |");
    System.out.println("|-------------------------|");
    System.out.println("|Wins                    12|");
    System.out.println("|Losses                  3|");
    System.out.println("|_________________________|");
```

Ignore the System.out.println()s in the second example it was just to set structure. My question is how do I get the | to line up with the rest and the name not to edit the spaces if that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to do some research into `String#format` and the formatting specifiers - maybe something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625364/i-want-to-manage-the-format-in-java/32625590#32625590)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically want to pad strings.

If the string is shorter than a certain length, then you want to add characters to it (either to the left or right) to make it reach that length. Right?

Use `System.out.printf`

```
System.out.printf("%-10s|", "John"); // padding to the right
```

That will output

```
John      |
```

Change the `10` to something else if you want the length to be something different.

For the number of wins and loses, you can pad the numbers to the left:

```
int playOneWin = 12;
int losses = 3;
System.out.printf("|Wins%21s|%n", playOneWin); // note that the "-" is gone, signifying padding left
System.out.printf("|Losses%19s|", losses); // 19 is written here because "Losses" has 2 more letters than "Wins", 
                                           // so we pad the string for 2 fewer characters
```

Output:

```
|Wins                   12|
|Losses                  3|
```

Comment: I would recommend `%n` rather than `\n` in the printf argument. You don't know for sure if you're on Linux or Windows.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Edited.